# Set ADB in TCP/IP Mode never ends

Tags: android, adb, tcp, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to debug via wifi but it seems that I can't connect my adb in tcpip mode. I execute the command `adb tcpip 5555`
but the cmd never returns me the control, it seems like adb is looping.

Has anyone ever had this problem? I have latest sdk update (21) and google usb drivers installed. Thank you[image]

Comment: ricky albert install app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en  and then try with your ip

Comment: Forgot to say that my device is NOT ROOTED, but I read that I can use wifi debug also with non rooted devices

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: ok you can do it but you need to connect it throw usb once

Comment: As you can see from terminal, my phone is currently connected via usb

Comment: rickyalbert same thing with me too

Answer (score 1):

once connect your device through usb cable to establish a tcpip connection over wifi

execute at terminal

```
adb kill-server

adb tcpic 5555
 * daemon not running. starting it now
 * daemon started successfully *
 restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

adb connect device_ip
 connected to device_ip:5555
```

Comment: Actually it worked! I used 'adb kill-server' and then immediately 'adb connect device_ip'. Now I disconnected my phone from usb, then I opened Android Studio but it says me "no connected devices". Do I miss something?

Comment: check adb devices on terminal

Comment: Well nowI got it worked, thanks! Stupid question: if I close tthe terminal do I lose the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your desktop and android device both connected to same wifi. I faced this problem when my device connected to mobile data.